# Layout for a heading chapter in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I create a heading layout like the figure below in Word 2016? I would like to maintain it in one style ref to generate a table of contents later.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created a new style called ChapterNo with outline numbering (that includes Chapter and non-breaking space as prefix before number).  Modify the style properties so it is 1.5 line spacing with 12pt after; applied a bottom border of 1.5pt thickness with bottom margin of 12pt; set up a right-aligned tab at the right margin (with a leader of None, ie NOT the option 4 ___ style of tab, as that style would be slightly indented at the left ie not flush with left margin when used after manual line break).

Use manual line break (SHIFT and ENTER) to create a blank line, press CTRL u to switch on underlining and insert a tab (to create the middle border), then switch off underlining again and insert another manual line break (SHIFT and ENTER) and type the heading text that you want.

You'll need to adjust the alignment of the "middle" border - to do that select the tab line only and modify the font so its position is raised 10pt.

(Depending on the thickness of the border you want, you'll need to adjust the font size of this underlined tab to match the thickness of the border applied to the paragraph style.)

As there's quite a few steps, you might find it easier to then copy and paste your heading block for each chapter, and then just modify the actual heading text.

See below for screenshot, including table of contents picking up this style.
[image]